# Custom method for ArrayList of custom object

Tags: java, android, oop, arraylist, subclass

Kind of a 2-part question.

PART I:

I have a custom class Contact that contains String: email, name, address, phone number. Note that different contacts may have the same email.

```
{dup@mail.com, Chris Cross, XXX, 122334455}
{dup@mail.com, Christian Cross, YYY, 2233445566}
```

I want to be able to go through an `ArrayList<Contact>` and delete Contacts against a list of found emails `ArrayList<String>`.

So, at some point I find myself wanting to write this:

```
for(String email : registeredEmails){
    while(contacts.contains(email)) {    // custom implementation of contains for ArrayList<Contact>
        Contact c = contacts.findContactByMail(email)  // custom method for ArrayList<Contact>
        contacts.remove(c);
    }
}
```

But everywhere I look, the overwhelming advice seems to be against this perfectly sensible construction.
I realize there are other ways of doing this that don't rely on creating findContactByEmail, but it is so much more readable this way.

It just feels right! So can I do this? It's not going to break anything is it? Aside from abstract debates about composition over inheritance, is there any reason I shouldn't do this?

Part II:
How do I do it? Do I subclass ArrayList? Then don't I end up with a MyArrayList`<Contact>`? Not the look I was going for...

Does the contains and findContactByEmail code go in my Contact class somewhere or where?

EDIT
Maybe a bit of background is required here.
This is in an Android app.

This all happens in the "Friends" section of the app. Basically, I get a list of phone contacts which the user can check off to send an invite.

However, it makes no sense to send an invite if the person already has the app installed. So I check the phone list against a list of installed users. Then back on the phone (in the android app) I want to delete these installed users from the phone book list before I display it(they go on a different "add friend" list). 
I'm now implementing this with an Iterator, but my first instinct was to go with a custom method "findContactByEmail" for ArrayList`<Contact>` and an override of contains that finds a match against String email.

Comment: I dont see any problems, in extending Arraylist and having your own new method. 

Once you create your own arraylist class, you can always have an instance for  MyArrayList<Contact>., but I would suggest having a DB query call, for the same. 

Looking at the question, am not sure, is the list fetched from a DB call or generated at runtime.

Comment: I don't really want MyArrayList<Contact>, I want to use ArrayList<Contact>, with the extra method findContactByEmail. This is in an Android app. I get the contact list off a phone and look up a db on a server for already installed users. I want to tidy up the contacts list before displaying it.

Comment: @grooble you're trying to make your code more readable, I get it. What I'm saying it's not maintainable trying to create a subclass of `ArrayList` to achieve the desired effect. Rather, leave the Java classes AS-IS and create utility classes or have relevant functions in your `Contact` class to make your work simpler.

Comment: Just create a static `findContactByEmail(List<Contact>, String)` method and a static `containsContactWithEmail(List<Contact>, String)` somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I find your approach difficult to maintain, especially from the viewpoint of other developers maintaining your code.

Oh, besides, a `List` interface contains an `contains` method already, so why create a new one?

There are 2 approaches you can take: Either create a utility class that handles your list of emails, e.g.,

```
public class Contacts {

    private Contacts() {
    }

    public static void removeEmails(List<String> emails, String emailAddressToRemove) {
        //Implementation here...
    }
}
```

<strike>Alternatively, if you're using Java 8, you can use predicate function and do a remove based on a predicate.</strike>

That way, you don't create your custom `ArrayList` subclass. Also, various frameworks returns a collection and by returning your custom `ArrayList` doesn't guarantee that others might subclass it to your custom `ArrayList` to use your specific method.

> Does the contains and findContactByEmail code go in my Contact class
>   somewhere or where?

I would, pretty much, put it in my Contact class as it's relevant to the Contact info.

Comment: I do not understand why should we write a method like this, we can simply pass the email to the DB and deletion. 

just iterate through the list of emails, and if present in the db, simply delete or fetch or do what ever you want.

Comment: The OP is getting contact from the phone and removing them from the list if it doesn't exist on the DB, not the other way around.

Comment: What if, we select only the ones required, instead if fetching all and removing the list.

Comment: I do not what which database he is using, in general we do
select * from contacts -- assuming contacts is the name of the table
here can use
select * from contacts where email not in ('a','b') -- where a & b are the emails we need to remove.

Comment: thanks for your comments. see the edit above for more explanation about what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala the emails on the DB are the ones who already have the app installed. The OP wants to take ALL his contacts from HIS phone book and remove those that ALREADY got the app (by getting all email addresses from DB and removing them from the phone contact list).

Comment: that is even more simple, you now have two contact lists, 1 from phone book and one from DB, what if I use phoneBookLst.removeAll(dbContactList)

Comment: That can work too. See, it's far beyond your approach you had earlier.

Comment: Phonebook list is <Contact>. List from server is String. So removeAll wont work as is, although I could make an arraylist of Contact from the list of String...

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you want to delete all the contacts who has installed the app, and invite others. you also might want to add new contacts. For this, we can have 3 methods,

1. **Delete contacts who has already installed the app**, for this you can send the list to the database and delete the contacts-- delete from contacts where email in ('a',b')
2. **Invite people to install** - for this you might pass a list (of contacts) as an argument to a method, which will iterate and send individual requests to each contact
3. **Add new contact** - this should be simple

I do not find any concern here.

Comment: Yes and this is all implemented.
My question is about how to override and ArrayList method for a custom class and how to add another custom method findContactByEmail for ArrayList<Contact> (not MyArrayList<Contact>) such that I can call: Contact c = contacts.findContactByEmail(email). No one has answered that yet.

Comment: Could you please explain, what is the output that you want from the below line

Contact c = contacts.findContactByEmail(email).

Comment: Why does that matter? I want to get a Contact back from contacts.findContactByEmail.

Comment: who have installed the app (available in the database) or all contact (available in phonebook)